# How to post-modify a C pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

In modern processors it is possible to load a register from memory and then post-modify the indexing pointer by a desired value. For example, in our embedded processor, this will be done by:

```
ldr r0, [r1], +12
```

which means - load the value pointed to by r1 into r0 and then increment r1 by 12:

```
r0 = [r1]
r1 = r1 + 12
```

In the C language, using pointer arithmetics, one can assign a value using a pointer and then advance the pointer by 1:

```
char i, *p, a[3]={10, 20, 30};

p = &(a[0]);
i = *p++;
// now i==10 and p==&(a[1]).
```

I am looking for a way to dereference a pointer while post-modifying it by an offset other than 1. Is this possible in C, so it maps nicely to the similar asm instruction?

Note that:

```
i = *p+=2;
```

increases the value in a[0] w/o modifying the pointer, and:

```
i = *(p+=2);
```

pre-modifies the pointer, so in this case `i==30`.

Comment: I take it that the answer "`i = *p; p += 12;` and use better optimization settings on your compiler so that it picks the right instructions" is not what you're after? ;-)

Comment: Why on earth do you want want to do this?

Comment: +1 for Steve. C isn't a syntactic sugar for assembler, it's another language and it's your compiler's job to translate it to the best asm possible on your machine and your instruction set.

Comment: It is a pity this doesn't work `*(int *)(( (int(*)[2])p  ) ++) )`

Comment: @SteveJessop - well, because it's not always generating the code I want. Having it done in a more explicit way may help the optimizer to understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Electro - b/c doing it Steve's way generates two instructions more often than not.

Comment: @Kos - thanks for pointing out the obvious. The reason I am asking this question is b/c some times the talented programmers at SE come up with ideas that did not occur to my limited brains.

Comment: What's so bad about `i = *p; p += 2;`? Seriously. An optimizing compiler that is worth its money will generate the instruction you want.

Comment: @unkulunkulu Is it, really? :)

Comment: @Damon: in which case as already stated, the compiler for this platform is not worth its money (or is run with the wrong options, maybe a `-march=` is needed). gcc is free though, so "not worth its money" is pretty dire ;-)

Comment: Gentlemen, consider this as an exercise in C. Forget the ASM part.

Comment: @unwind, why not, there're uglier things out there :D

Comment: @ysap: if you want to write C that explicitly "does a load and post-modify", I suppose you could define `inline char ldr_char(char **pp, size_t off) { char c = **pp; *pp += off; return c; }`. That lets you write `i = ldr_char(&p, 2);`. The ASM part I'm ignoring/forgetting is that if the compiler can't produce the instruction you want from my first code, it won't produce it from this either.

Comment: IMHO, if your compiler isn't generating "optimal" code for the human-readable version, it's very unlikely that any of us is going to guess what convolution is required in order to make it more optimal.

Comment: @SteveJessop - Right. The easiest way to get my copy of GCC to produce a single post-modify instruction is the code from your first comment. And this is how it should be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. **Yes this is possible.**
2. **You shouldn't be doing weird pointer math to make it happen.**
3. Not only is it about optimization settings, **your GCC back-end needs to *tell* GCC that it has such a feature** (i.e. when GCC itself is being compiled). Based on this knowledge, GCC automatically combines the relevant sequence into a single instruction.

i.e. if your back-end is written right, even something like:

```
 a = *ptr;
 ptr += SOME_CONST;
```

should become a single post-modify instruction.

**How to correctly set this up when writing a back-end?** (ask your friendly neighbourhood GCC back-end developer to do it for you):

If your GCC back-end is called `foo`:

1. In the GCC source tree, the back-end description and hooks will be located at `gcc/config/foo/`.
2. Among the files there (which get compiled along with GCC), there is usually a header `foo.h` which contains a lot of `#defines` describing machine features.
3. GCC expects that a back-end which supports post-increment define the macro `HAVE_POST_INCREMENT` to evaluate to true, and if it supports post-modify, then define the macro `HAVE_POST_MODIFY_DISP` to true. (post-increment => `ptr++`, post-modify => `ptr += CONST`). Maybe there are a few other things to be handled as well.

Assuming that your processor's back-end has got this right, lets move to **what happens when you compile your code** containing said post-modify sequence:

*There is a specific GCC optimization pass* that goes through instruction pairs that fall into this category and combines them. The source for that pass is [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/gcc/auto-inc-dec.c?view=markup), and has a rather clear description of what GCC will do and how to get it to do it.

*But this, in the end, is not in your control as a GCC user. It is in the control of the developer who wrote your GCC back-end. All you should be doing, like the most upvoted comment says, is:*

```
 a = *ptr;
 ptr += SOME_CONST;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a valuable info.

Comment: @ysap - Since you 'accepted' this answer, I am curious: Did you have your GCC back-end fixed? (I assume a colleague of yours wrote it). Or was it always working correctly?

Comment: ArjunShankar, it is not really a colleague, but a contractor. The compiler is still in development, and I am trying to make sense in some of the compiled code. The definitions you mentioned above do appear in the header file (sort of), and I can make it generate the code I want in some tests, but sometimes, the compiler decides on a different optimization strategy (which makes sense locally, but can be improved in a global view).

Comment: Specifically, the alternative is to use a load-with-offset where the pointer is unchanged during the loop and the offset increases accordingly, and then increment the pointer at the end of the loop iteration. So, I was looking for a way to hint the optimizer to generate the code I want and so make the higher-level optimization even better.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way, but don't do it:

```
i = *((p += 2) - 2);
```

(not exactly post-modify)

Comment: Interesting idea, but really needs to be tested "in the field". My bet is that this will actually generate a really convoluted code, instead of a simple load-post-modify asm instruction...

Comment: Or `i = (p += 2)[-2];` for that matter. But people writing code like this are publicly humiliated, hang, torn, and quartered where I work... Code should never give someone reading it a "WTF?" thought at first sight, even if it saves a cycle or two. It should always be obvious and intuitive first.

Comment: The array notation `i = (p += 2)[ - 2];` is even more funky. Or the other way round: ` i = (-2)[ p += 2];`  ;-) @Damon: Ahh, great minds think alike ...

Comment: @wildplasser - the 2nd form - exactly what I wanted to say ;-)

Comment: I put some parens around the unary minus, but it appears the [] binds stronger than the unary minus. Should work without the (), but it does not feel right. Good reason to avoid the pattern...

Comment: Because I was curious, this generated 6 asm instructions on Visual Studio 2010.  @Steve Jessop's solution in the comments also generated 6 instructions that were almost identical.

Comment: Of course, in addition to being curious I'm not that smart, and had optimizations turned off :)  With full optimization on, both versions do appear to compile to a single asm `mov`.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can think of:

```
#define POST_INDEX_ASSIGN(lhs, ptr, index)  (lhs = *(ptr), (ptr) += (index))

POST_INDEX_ASSIGN(i, p, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks. That's basically what Steve suggested in the 1st comment.

Comment: But unfortunately an expression statement like: `x = POST_INDEX_ASSIGN(i, p, 1) + POST_INDEX_ASSIGN(j, p, 2);` is undefined in C.

Answer (score 1):

```
i = *p; 
p = (unsigned char*)p + 12;
```

where i is any kind of type and p is a pointer to that type.

If you don't add the typecast, the pointer increment will be done in steps with size == `sizeof(*p)`, which would make the code completely different from the posted assembler.

For example, had p been an `int*` on a 32-bit system, the pointer would have been incremented 4*12 bytes without the typecast.

Comment: Are you sure you meant `unsigned char`? An unsigned char is just 1 byte and not wide enough to hold a pointer. Plus, it is not a pointer type at all.

Comment: Obviously, it should be `(unsigned char *)`.

Comment: Oops, thank you, fixed. (Although the result would be the same, ironically).